# How to conduct a panel regression on this data in R?

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis, panel-data

In R I have a table "education":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orWRv.png)

(my full table is much larger, it has more countries, indicators and years

I need to use panel regression in R to verify the hypothesis that a higher level of education leads to better health.

I tried this way:

```
library(plm)
education$Indicator <- gsub("Perceived health", "Perceived_health", education$Indicator)

education$Time <- as.Date(paste0(education$Time, "-01-01"))

perceived_health_data <- subset(education, Indicator == "Perceived health")

model <- plm(Value ~ Education, data = perceived_health_data, model = "within")

summary(model)
```

but this error appeared:

> Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  :
> 0 (non-NA) cases

How can I do that? Do I have to create dummies or sth?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, Agnieszka. Please take a minute to check out the Dos and Don'ts for asking questions (e.g. why it's good to provide sample data and not so good to post screenshots): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ; that said, please make sure your configuration recognizes commas (instead of points) for decimal separators (see column "values") or otherwise replace accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted my data but it changed into a photo automatically.
Yes, the commas are not the problem, they have changed into dots in R. (the screen is from excel)

Comment: To provide sample data, paste the output of `dput(data_frame)`, where data_frame is a sufficient *subset* of your data (unless your data has just a couple of rows). Anyhow: you 're filtering your data for `Indicator == "Perceived health"`, while two steps earlier you've replaced "Perceived health" with "Perceived_health".  Check with `nrow(perceived_health_data)` which should be zero, i. e. no matching observations.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to Indicator == "Perceived_health" and it worked, but there was also a warning message: 
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")

Moreover: nrow(perceived_health_data)
[1] 1566

Do you think it is ok or should I change sth?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is more related to data cleaning than running the regression. In `plm` the procedure is

```
library("plm")

data("Produc", package = "plm")

fe <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
            data = Produc, 
            index = c("state","year"),
            method="within")

summary(fe)
```

Define your panel-identifier, i.e. unit and time, e.g. `Country` and `Time`. I do not see why you want to paste a date format to Time. Years are totally fine. So your code could be

```
model <- plm(Value ~ Education, 
             data = perceived_health_data, 
             index = c("Country","Time"),
             model = "within")
```

You can perhaps share at least the structure of your data for others to check if there are potential problems with `str(perceived_health_data)` or share some part of it from `glimpse(perceived_health_data)`.

Note that your `Value` seems to measure two things, health and unemployment. Run the model on each outcome. You can filter in Excel or R. It's recommended to build a tidy / clean dataframe where you have two columns `Unemployment` and `Health` instead of `Value`.